# Can I use PC3L RAM on my 2010 MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I tried googling but didn't get any adequate results.

I have a 13 inch MacBook Pro mid-2010 and would like to upgrade the RAM. I have a ram module which says this on the front:

> 8GB 2Rx8 PC3L-12800S-11-13-F3

and the company is SK Hynix.

On Apple's [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201165) it states that PC3 RAM is needed. However, I'm wondering if my PC3L RAM would work. My current RAM is 4 GB and if I used this I could potentially increase it to 10 GB.

I ask because sometimes Apple's support pages don't give you the whole answer. For example, it is [possible to have up to 16 GB of ram on my Mac model](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42426/can-i-upgrade-my-macbook-mid-2010-to-16gb-of-ram-2x8g), but the Apple site says only 8 GB is possible. So I'm wondering whether my PC3L RAM could be used as well.

P.S. I don't want my Mac to explode or anything

Comment: Apple spec is 204-pin **PC3-8500** (1066 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM. I don't think this RAM will work because it is **PC3L-12800**. DataMemorySystems [sells compatible RAM](http://www.datamemorysystems.com/apple-macbook-pro-intel-core-2-duo-2-66ghz-13-mc375ll/a-mid-2010-memory-upgrades/) rather inexpensively. Disclaimer: satisfied customer only - no financial ties to DataMem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that it will work. It depends on whether the 8GB 2Rx8 PC3L-12800S-11-13-F3 also works in 1.5 V mode (instead of 1.35 V - PC3L means **PC3 L**ow voltage).

If 1.5 V are allowed you will find a similar question and answers here: [Can I use DDR3 1600MHz RAM in a Mac instead of 1067MHz?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115267/can-i-use-ddr3-1600mhz-ram-in-a-mac-instead-of-1067mhz)

In the comments you will find the hint to keep one of the slower modules mounted  - then it may work if your MBP isn't too picky. **I don't recommend the approach though**.

Comment: Hey tyvm! A few questions: I think I found my module on Amazon [here](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00ILWIAEW/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1483574355&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=hmt41gs6bfr8a&dpPl=1&dpID=51QdZhzQUgL&ref=plSrch) and the RAM there looks correct except for three things: 1) It's says `Korea` and mine says `China`. 2) It says `1506` but mine says `1541`. The former is probably the manufacture location but I'm worried about the latter. Assuming that 1) and 2) aren't problems, the Amazon description states that it is compatible with the mid-2012 MacBook Pro, so would…

Comment: …that imply that it would also work for the mid-2010 MacBook Pro? I think the seller didn't mention it because it's not "officially" supported but from that link in my post for the 13 inch model that I have 8 GB is accepted. Also I found a module on the official website [here](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3+SDRAM&srnm=HMT41GS6AFR8A&rk=20&rc=module) and it states that it is "backwards compatible with 1.5 V." *However* this module does not have the `PB` at the end of the description as the Amazon one does (which is basically my one) so do you think that backward…

Comment: …compatibility comment applies for me as well? The site might have been talking about all models including the `PB` one but I don't know enough about RAM to tell. Also, the commenter on this post said that it might not work because it is `12800`. Do you think that's a problem? Sorry for the long comments! I just want to make sure my laptop doesn't mess up because I won't be able to buy a new one!

Comment: Jjust went to the RAM's website that I commented, scrolled down a bit, clicked on the name of the RAM and opened the PDF and read it a bit. It seems like `PB` is a "grade" of RAM. So the fact that it says "backward compatible with 1.5 V" and "data transfer rates: …, PC3-8500" should mean that it will work with the Mac, because the Mac needs 1.5 V and a data transfer rate of 8500. Would that be correct? Also it seems like the `PB` grade is DDR3L-1600 according to the PDF. The link *you* posted suggestes that shouldn't be a problem because it'll "downclock" to 1066, is that so? Sorry for the Qs!

Comment: Okay so I think I just about have it. On the website in the second PDF it says that the `PB` grade's "Module Nominal Voltage, VDD" is "1.35V/1.5V Operable." That works because my Mac needs 1.5 V. The site says that the HMT41GS6AFR8A supports a transfer rate of PC3-8500, which is what my Mac is. Not sure if it's for the `PB` grade but it seems to be for all grades because it's on the website. The second PDF doesn't say anything about it but can I safely assume it? And from your link it looks like 1600 MHz will work at 1066 MHz with little problems. So I install *just* this 8 GB and all is good?

Comment: @Ram12800 The RAM module seems to specified for use on older logic boards. But: it doesn't necessarily mean that it works in your Mac. You have to try it and you need a good money back guarantee.

Comment: Oh, it was given to me by a friend so I was just trying it out! Anyway, it didn't work sadly. My Mac made those beeping noises upon boot. I tried it in the other slot and that time nothing happened at all -- the screen stayed blank. Looks like that didn't work then, even though I was so convinced it would. Thanks a ton for the help anywa!